# OpenIdConnect token renewal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect, identityserver4

We have an MVC application that uses IdentityServer4 as a STS. We have set the `access_token` and `identity_token` lifetime to four hours on the `Client` properties in the STS. We have also added the scope `offline_access` in our MVC client.

How do we refresh the `access_token` and/or the `identity_token` from the STS in the MVC client?

What could work, but I don't see this as a good solution is request a new token on every request. Should we keep track of this time in the MVC client and call something like: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/293622b8438d27f4c9c2574e43fe92a22560ac6b/Clients/src/MvcHybrid/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L46 
Or is there some event that we can hook up to and request the new token(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't refresh identity tokens - only access tokens.

There is no event - either refresh tokens pro-actively based on expiration time - or wait until the API returns a 401 and refresh lazily.

Comment: We used the System.IdentityModel package to check if the current access token is expired or is about to expire. If this condition is true we request a new access token with something like the sample code. Thanks for the clarification!